# How to load dynamic Jenkinsfile during a build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline job that uses different Jenkinsbuild files depending on the job parameter. Is there a way to load the Jenkins build file during the execution of the job, something like:

```
node {
   stage("Determine build parameter") {
      String jenkinsFile = .....
   }
   // here the Jenkins build file should be loaded
   loadSomeHowBuildFile jenkinsFile

   // ... and then the pipeline steps defined in the jenkinsFile are executed 
}
```

It would be really great is this will work...

Comment: please add and accept an answer so folks know you got it sorted out and so your solution can help others in the future.

Comment: @burnettk I'm not really sure how to do this. I don't see any check mark or something like that to accept or mark the question as accepted?

Comment: you have to submit an answer first. that's the one you ultimately can accept (when you have enough cred).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution which is quite simple. Jenkins only needs to load the file

```
node {
   stage("Determine build file") {
      String jenkinsFile = /path/to/Jenkins/build/file
   }
   // Here the Jenkins build file is loaded and executed
   load jenkinsFile
}
```

Comment: Does the jenkinsfile you load to have a certain structure? In other questions regarding how to load code dynamically, it is stressed that the code must end with a `return this` statement.